# Make another ajax call to get headers before each actual ajax call - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication, promise

I have to make an async call which uses cookie to get bearer token which has to be passed to make actual ajax call for the resource.
And I have written the following code which works awesome and get's me the result.

Can I use **ajaxPrefilter** or **beforeSend** options to get the tokens, I tried to find documentation for ajaxPrefilter which says it accepts a function, but does that waits for that function to be finished before making actual call?

Token retrieval function

```
function getTokenUsingCookieAsync() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            $.ajax('/retrieve-token').done(function (result) {
                resolve(result.token);
            }).fail(function (message) {
                reject(message);
            });
        });
    }
```

Actual execute function:

```
function execute(url, method, data) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    getTokenUsingCookieAsync().then(function (response) {
        var reqSettings = {
            async: true,
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            type: method,
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer '+ response,
            },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
        };
        $.ajax(reqSettings).done(function (result) {
            deferred.resolve(result);
        }).fail(function (message) {
            deferred.reject(message);
        });
    }).catch(function (message) {
        deferred.reject(message);
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

So the following pseudo code is possible or not?

```
$.ajaxPrefilter((options) => {
            $.ajax('/retrieve-token').done((result) => {
                options.headers =  {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${result}`
              };
         });
    });

 $.ajax('actual-url')
    .done(whatever);
```

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want because the prefilter and/or beforeSend are expected to be syncrhonous - or, at the very least any results of asynchronous code inside those functions will not be available to the request

Comment: Promise constructor and deferred anti-patterns - your code can be far cleaner - see https://jsfiddle.net/3ngbtnj9/